# Arrayformula to count X when C

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to count the cells they have `o!` or `%`

I want to count them or v  witch have in the front cell from the row an o! or %

```
="o!: "&count(arrayformula(and($D9:H$67="o!",(E8:E67=Or("v","m")))))&", %: "&count(arrayformula(and($D9:H$67="%",(E8:E67=OR("v","m")))))
```

but nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste in D9 cell instead all those formulas per each row:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B9:B="",,IF(B9:B < TODAY(), "o!", "o")))
```

then to count for `m` or `v` if D column is `!o` you do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(N((D9:D="o!")*(REGEXMATCH(F9:F, "m|v")))))
```

[image]

and J6 would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("o!: "&SUM(N(($D$9:$D="o!")*(REGEXMATCH(F9:F, "m|v"))))&
            ", %!: "&SUM(N(($D$9:$D="%!")*(REGEXMATCH(F9:F, "m|v")))))
```

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1njz5jnSZScRPFpGm0FZjr-AZFWYDglzV0EHwrf5fsUk/edit)

Comment: @MatthiasRuffieux added demo sheet and answer updated

Comment: Thnks you ar my hero